# How can I locate lanes where I can legally drive a 4x4 in the UK?

Tags: uk

As above really, is there a resource where I can find all the "off-road" style lanes in the UK where I could legally drive a 4x4?

Comment: It seems appropriate to add the link to the meta on 4x4 issues: http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/205/299

I'm not convinced that a question like this is on-topic, particularly since you are basically asking about driving cars around, but it deserves more discussion.

Comment: @Greg.Ley - this is more of an access issue - green-laning is fairly popular outdoor activity in the UK, but there are restrictions on where you can legally partake in the activity.

Comment: @HorusKol - Interesting. I'm not familiar with "green-laning." Are you saying that this question is akin to asking whether one can ride their bike/4x4/scooter/whatever in a Wilderness area or national park in the US? Because that would be a totally legit access question in my mind.

Comment: @Greg.Ley It's similar - green laning tends to refer more to disused back country lanes rather than open land, but the concept is relatively similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are marked on OS 1:25K Explorer maps as "Byways open to all traffic".

But it's a good idea to research your route beforehand as some (like the [Monk's Trod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monks_Trod)) are now closed by traffic regulation orders - primarily because of the damage caused by off-roaders.

[image: Key from OS map]